# How to add shadow to separate letters in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a small challenge: 
  how to add shadow to each letter in the header?
I tried this but add shadow to the whole div not to separate letter... 
shall i wrap each letter in a span or what is the solution ?

```
 h2 {
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `text-shadow` instead of `box-shadow`

Edit:
*text-shadow* doesn't have a *spread* value

Using your example it would be:

```
h2 {
  -webkit-text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an important note to the answer of Ricardo Ribeiro i'd add that in this way compatibility is "limited" in IE to the version 10+
For versions < 10 till 5.5 a proprietary filter can be used as fallback:

```
h2 {
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#xxxxxx,direction=[int],strength=[int])
}
```

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I can't edit the answer right now but feel free to edit my answer and include that note (giving credit to yourself)